# How to reload JSON with AJAX every 10 Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to reload a JSON file every 10 seconds with JQUERY.

The page is here: http://moemonty.com/chirp/chirp.html

The Code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
 <!-- included Jquery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
 <!-- jquery library -->
  </head>
<body>  
 <script>

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //disallows cachinge, so information should be new


function loadChirp(){ //start function

var url = "http://www.chirpradio.org/json";
        $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22"+url+"%22&format=json&callback=?", 
            function(data){
            console.log(data.query.results.json);

                document.write('The artist is: ' + data.query.results.json.artist + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The artist is: ' + data.query.results.json["record-label"] + '<br/><br/>' );

                document.write('The album is: ' + data.query.results.json.album + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The record label is: ' + data.query.results.json["record-label"] + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The feedback link is: ' + data.query.results.json["feedback-link"] + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The database id is: ' + data.query.results.json["database-id"] + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The time is: ' + data.query.results.json.timestamp.time + ' ');

                document.write(data.query.results.json.timestamp["am-pm"] + '<br/><br/>');

                document.write('The current dj is: ' + data.query.results.json["current-dj"] + '<br/><br/>');


                setTimeout("loadChirp()",5000);
                alert('The timeout was triggered.');

            }); 

} //end function        


$(document).ready(function(){ 
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
    loadChirp();
}); 
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION 


</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: *doesn't seem to be working* is not a very precise problem description. What is the expected result, what is the actual result (error message, HTTP status code)?

Comment: Well what *does* happen?

Comment: Also, even if the timeout code did work, I don't think all those `document.write` calls will do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want the previous set of returned data replaced by the new set, instead of appending it. In that case, using jQuery you can do:

```
<div id='content'></div>
<script>
     function loadChirp(){
         $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22"+url+"%22&format=json&callback=?", 
              function(data) {
                  $('#content').html('The artist is: ' + data.query.results.json.artist + '<br/><br/>');
              }); 
         setTimeout("loadChirp()",5000);
      }
</script>
```

etc...

Comment: Good answer, but `setTimeout("loadChirp()",5000);` should be `setTimeout(loadChirp,5000);` It's almost never appropriate to pass a string into `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Comment: the question was to reload every 10 seconds, so it should be: setInterval(loadChirp,10000);

Comment: Should be setTimeout(loadChirp,10000); without () or "" on the loadChirp function. Calling the function with execution "()" should unleash a horrible recursion.

Comment: Is this considered an expensive thing to do or normal? I have a similar situation where I need to I need to update a table when a play button is pressed and it should keep getting the data from the api until the stop button is pressed, (this is regardless of whether there's new data in the web service).

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the **loop** to work as quoted, but there could be a subtlety around the fact you're using JSONP. I would change the `setTimeout` call to:

```
setTimeout(loadChirp, 5000);
```

...for a couple of reasons. First off, using the function reference rather than a code string is a better idea generally, and second off, you're quite certain that you're getting the right function reference (whereas with the string, what reference you get depends on the context in which the code is executed).

But as Pointy pointed out in a comment, there's a separate issue: `document.write` will not do what you probably want it to do there. You can only use `document.write` to write to the HTML stream that's being parsed as part of the original page load. After the page load, you can't use it anymore. Consider using jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and similar functions to add to the DOM after page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `console.log(data.query.results.json);` - console is not defined.
Also, you can use `setInterval( "function()", 5000 );`.

Comment: `console` will be defined on a lot of browsers (Firefox, Chrome, ...), and not on IE. I'm guessing if he's using it, he's using a browser where it's supported.

Comment: Just to be more specific, if you use setInterval, call it on document ready, not inside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use:

> setInterval("loadChirp", 10000):

Don't write loadCrirp() inside setInterval as we're only passing a refrence

Comment: *"Don't write loadCrirp() inside setInterval as we're only passing a refrence"* Then why does your example still pass a string? You need to remove the quotes to pass a reference to the function; otherwise, `setInterval` will evaluate the string, which will have no effect (it won't call the function, for instance).