# How to auto update data in a View using Json and Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Using MVC I have a Controller that gets data from a database and display it in a view.  Working great as I press F5 to "update" the view/page with new data.

However, I would like to update the page with new data every x seconds without having to refresh the page itself - I only want the data to update, not the page.  I understand that I can use a JSON Controller to do this but I cannot find any good information or tutorial about this.

I have been doing this before using PHP and Ajax/JavaScript, but now I need to do the same using MVC.

Anyone know about any tutorials on how to update data on a web page every x seconds using MVC and JSON?

Comment: You should look into SignalR.

Comment: See the following links:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011780/how-does-gmails-periodic-mail-fetching-work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804097/how-to-reload-json-with-ajax-every-10-seconds